# C# BackgoundWorker return a value

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have the following code in the static class:

```
public static string ExchangeDataAsync(string request)
{
   BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

   bgWorker.DoWork             += (obj, e) => ExchangeData(request, e);
   bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (obj, e) => ExchangeCompleted(obj, e);

   bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); 

   // I NEED T0 RETURN DATA HERE
}

private static void ExchangeData(string request, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  // do some work
  e.Result = some_result;   
}

private static void ExchangeCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{ 
  MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());   
}
```

It works OK and I can see my result in ExchangeCompleted method. But how can I access this result in first method? Is there a way to get result from bgWorker object?

I use it in another class like this(so ExchangeDataAsync should return me a value):

```
string response = Global.ExchangeDataAsync(request);
```

**UPD.**

sharpcloud is right. function is not async in that case. do you have any good suggestions how to return value to another class from exchangecompleted method?

Comment: If you are targeting .Net 4.5 you can use the new Async/Await feauture (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) instead of the BackgroundWorker

Comment: Then why do it asynchronously at all? Because obviously you want to block execution until you get the response.

Comment: I use .Net 4 in my project

Comment: You are right. It will not be async in that case. So what is a good way to return value in that case? From another class.

Comment: This is a logical fallacy of course.  Whatever code you intend to put at the comment needs to go in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler instead.

Comment: I understand it already. I have some idea about this problem: send a delegate from another class to this code and call delegate in ExchangeCompleted method, so it will return result to caller. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass e (instance of RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) to ExchangeCompleted method. And use Result property of passed e.